# SASS loop to generate chained :not() from variables string

Tags: css, sass

I have a long list of classes I wish to use in a couple of ways.

The list looks something like this (but much longer):

```
$my-components: '.some-component', '.some-other-component', '.another-component';
```

One of the ways I need to use this list of class names in SASS (scss), which I can't figure out, is to create a long chained selector of `:not()`s. The final rendered output should look like this:

```
.parent {
  > * {
    &:last-of-type:not(.some-component):not(.some-other-component):not(.another-component):not(etc) {
      // style rules
    }
  }
}
```

(The goal being to select the last child element of .parent that doesn't have one of the classes in the list).

**Question:** How can I make the above code DRY by using the `$my-components` variable?

Note 1: The loop's output needs to be able to be appended to that `&:last-of-type`, as in above example.

Note 2: I'm using the `$my-components` variable already in a different function, so I'd like to keep it in the same format if possible.

Note 3: I know this seems hacky and stupid, and that I should just give all of those elements a common shared class instead. But unfortunately I can not currently modify that part of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a @each loop

### scss:

```
$my-components: '.some-component', '.some-other-component', '.another-component';

.parent {
    > * {
        $selector: '';
        @each $component in $my-components {
            $selector: $selector + ":not(#{$component})"
        }
        &:last-of-type#{$selector} {
            color: blue;
        }    
    }
}
```

### css:

```
.parent > *:last-of-type:not(.some-component):not(.some-other-component):not(.another-component) {
  color: blue;
}
```

#### What's happening ?

I define a new string variable `$selector`.
During the `@each` loop, I'm concatening the string with `:not(#{$component})` to add your new selector.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much, this does exactly what I need.